# CakePHP: using a different users table

Tags: cakephp, authentication

After setting up the simple Cakephp login concept I would like to let CakePHP use a different table to check the users and the login. I can't figure out how to change the table name within the Auth-component.

Below my basic Controller. How can I let Cakephp know it has to look into a different database table?

```
class AppController extends Controller {
  public $components = array(
      'Session',
      'Auth'=>array(
          'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index'),
          'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index'),
          'authError'=>"You can't access that page",
          'authorize'=>array('Controller')
      )
  );

  public function isAuthorized($user) {
      return true;
  }

  public function beforeFilter() {
      //$this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');

      $this->set('siteCategory', 'home');   
      $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
      $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Best Solution:

This is something that's done in the `User` model with the `useTable` property.

I.e. in `app/Model/User.php` you should have something like this:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'table_name';

    //... rest of Model stuff here

}
```

### Alternative:

Alternatively you can specify a different model to be used for the user, although I don't think that's what you're asking for. If I'm wrong there though, just set the `userModel` value like this:

```
public $components = array(
      'Auth'=>array(
          'authenticate'=>array(
              'Form' => array('userModel' => 'ADifferentUserModel')
)));
```

Comment: What about other models where "User" table is being used for other stuff. e.g Profile Model will be looking for "table_name" instead of users.

Comment: Is there any way I will change table name to "users_cake", and it will be reflected to whole site without changing name to all controllers??

Comment: Yes, you can do this. In the model just use this: `public $useTable = "users_cake";`
Ideally you would have the tables named to match the models, but in some cases this isn't possible, so you can do that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Earlier I tried this, It works but problem is in profile or other controllers where User has been used as model(I don't want to change it in whole app)